# How to integrate Testrail with Karate

Tags: karate, testrail

Is it possible to integrate karate with testrail? I am using below code to call the testrail but not sure how to send the results to testrail for each scenario.

```
@AfterClass
    public static void after() throws Exception
    {
        APIClient client = new APIClient("http://test.com/testrail");
        client.setUser("test");
        client.setPassword("Password1");
       JSONObject c = (JSONObject) client.sendGet("/get_case/5905");
       System.out.println(c.get("title"));


    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to integrate karate with testrail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48785037/how-to-integrate-karate-with-testrail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version 0.7.0.RC4 of Karate has support for an 'after' hook.

Refer to this example for details: [`hooks.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/develop/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/hooks/hooks.feature)

So getting results from Karate is solved using [`karate.info`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#the-karate-object). How you call TestRail is up to you.

Comment: Thanks Peter for the quick response.

Comment: @p.kop15 you had asked for load testing support in Karate, and now it is possible, can you try this out: https://github.com/ptrthomas/karate-gatling-demo

Comment: @TremAibar there is no direct support. please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54527955/143475