# How to integrate karate with testrail

Tags: java, cucumber, karate, testrail

I am new to Java and using karate for API automation. I need help to integrate testrail with karate. I want to use tags for each scenario which will be the test case id (from testrail) and I want to push the result 'after the scenario'.

Can someone guide me on this? Code snippets would be more appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Your question is too broad. can you be more specific with your question in the sense sharing what is your effort so far ?

Answer (score 4):

I spent a lot of effort for this.
That's how I implement. Maybe you can follow it.

First of all, you should download the `APIClient.java` and `APIException.java` files from the link below.

[TestrailApi in github](https://github.com/gurock/testrail-api/tree/master/java/com/gurock/testrail)

Then you need to add these files to the following path in your project.
For example: `YourProjectFolder/src/main/java/testrails/`

In your karate-config.js file, after each test, you can send your case tags, test results and error messages to the BaseTest.java file, which I will talk about shortly.

`karate-config.js file`

```
function fn() {

  var config = {
    baseUrl: 'http://111.111.1.111:11111',
  };
        
    
  karate.configure('afterScenario', () => {
    try{
         const BaseTestClass = Java.type('features.BaseTest');
         BaseTestClass.sendScenarioResults(karate.scenario.failed, 
         karate.scenario.tags, karate.info.errorMessage);
        }catch(error) {
       console.log(error)
       }
    });
      
   return config;
}
```

Please dont forget give tag to scenario in Feature file.
For example **@1111**

```
Feature: ExampleFeature

  Background:
    * def conf = call read('../karate-config.js')
    * url conf.baseUrl

  @1111
  Scenario: Example
```

Next, create a runner file named `BaseTests.java`

`BaseTest.java file`

```
package features;

import com.intuit.karate.junit5.Karate;
import net.minidev.json.JSONObject;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import testrails.APIClient;
import testrails.APIException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

public class BaseTest {

    private static APIClient client = null;
    private static String runID = null;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void beforeClass() throws Exception {
        String fileName = System.getProperty("karate.options");
        //Login to API
        client = new APIClient("Write Your host, for example 
        https://yourcompanyname.testrail.io/");
        client.setUser("user.name@companyname.com");
        client.setPassword("password");

        //Create Test Run
        Map data = new HashMap();
        data.put("suite_id", "Write Your Project SuitId(Only number)");
        data.put("name", "Api Test Run");
        data.put("description", "Karate Architect Regression Running");


        JSONObject c = (JSONObject) client.sendPost("add_run/" + 
        TESTRAİL_PROJECT_ID, data);
        runID = c.getAsString("id");
    }
       //Send Scenario Result to Testrail
    public static void sendScenarioResults(boolean failed, List<String> tags, String errorMessage) {
        try {
            Map data = new HashMap();
            data.put("status_id", failed ? 5 : 1);
            data.put("comment", errorMessage);
            client.sendPost("add_result_for_case/" + runID + "/" + tags.get(0), 
            data);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (APIException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Karate.Test
    Karate ExampleFeatureRun() {
        return Karate.run("ExampleFeatureRun").relativeTo(getClass());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look at 'hooks' documented here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#hooks

And there is an example with code over here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/hooks/hooks.feature

I'm sorry I can't help you with how to push data to testrail, but it may be as simple as an HTTP request. And guess what Karate is famous for :)

Note that values of tags can be accessed within a test, here is the doc for `karate.tagValues` (with link to example): https://github.com/intuit/karate#the-karate-object

Note that you need to be on the 0.7.0 version, right now 0.7.0.RC8 is available.

Edit - also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54527955/143475