# How to integrate Allure Report in karate API automation project

Tags: karate, allure, jira-xray, extent, reportportal

We are using Karate heavily for various projects and though the report generated using [karate Reports](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo#example-report) are more than anyone would need. I am still interested in getting Allure integrated in the mix.

Added allure-junit4 dependency and added allure listener

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                         <!-- -Dcucumber.options="&#45;&#45;plugin io.qameta.allure.cucumberjvm.AllureCucumberJvm"-->
                    </argLine>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>listener</name>
                            <value>io.qameta.allure.junit4.AllureJunit4</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>

                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

Now allure-results is getting created and I can see report but it's almost blank.

[image: Generated Allure Report]

How can I get allure report generated on karate based project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Allure supports the Cucumber JSON output it should work. Else suggest you take this up with the Allure team.

You can refer to this thread (for Extent): https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/619

EDIT: Since I refer anyone asking about extending / custom reports to this answer, read on.

In Karate 1.0 onwards, the `Results` object can be used to get *all* data about the test results. Also multiple JSON files will be output to the `<build>/karate-reports`. You can even re-try some tests and merge the results: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide#retry-framework-experimental

Also please be aware of changes to the Java hooks, it is called `RuntimeHook` now: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide#hooks

For those using XRay - there is official documentation: https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Testing+APIs+using+Karate+DSL

Regarding Report Portal - there is a need for the official adapter to be upgraded: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60156120/143475 - but that thread has a few links to examples of people who have done it.

Comment: I remember somone integrated allure already! Though mine is generating report but missing major info in details.

Comment: @AmitVyas Did you find a good way to integrate karate with Allure?

Comment: @TestingCodes were you able to integrate allure with karate? I am interested as well.