# Generate report and integrate it with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, karate

I am new in Karate but know almost all the basics. I want to generate a report for my test cases which will be kept in the folder for history purposes. currently, I am using the HTML report which overrides or updates every time I run my test cases.

If you can recommend me a step-by-step tutorial or a link, or simply give me a hint on how to approach this.

I have tried to use the `allure` framework and I am struggling to set it up.
Thought it would be the best approach to solve my problem.

Attached is my HTML report I am talking about. Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JUnit HTML report which you have referred to as an image is designed for easy development, so when working on a test, you re-run and re-fresh the browser.

What we recommend is to use the [parallel runner reports](https://github.com/intuit/karate#test-reports). Most of the time, 3rd party frameworks will solve this problem for you - especially if you use them integrated with CI. See [this for example](https://github.com/damianszczepanik/cucumber-reporting/blob/master/.README/trends.png).

But finally, Karate will output the industry-standard Cucumber JSON report format, so you can always write a reporting solution yourself. Note that others have had success integrating Allure - so please refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54527955/143475