# Karate - I am trying to integrate cucumber plugin for azure devops with my karate scripts

Tags: karate

I am trying to integrate cucumber plugin for azure devops with my karate scripts.

It requires adding following command to the runner file:

--format=json:./results/cucumber.json

Please help me how can i add this command or is there any source i can refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to do anything extra if you use the parallel `Runner`. Just configure Azure to look in the right place for the JSON files.

Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55828128/143475

Comment: Hi Peter,
I am trying to integrate the following plugin https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MaciejMaciejewski.azure-pipelines-cucumber&ssr=false#overview

This requires adding the following command:
--format=json:./results/cucumber.json

I trying without this command as you mentioned above but its not working. Please help

Comment: @user1873274 read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#test-reports - if that doesn't help you - please assume what you are asking for is not supported by karate. all the best