# Importing cucumber json result from karate feature file to Xray

Tags: karate, jira-xray

I am trying to call "POST /rest/raven/1.0/import/execution/cucumber/multipart" for Import Execution Results - REST

As this endpoint allows you to send two JSON files, I am written the below karate test

@UploadResultMultiPartURL
Scenario: To export execution result to xray Test plan
Given path 'import/execution/cucumber/multipart'
And header Authorization = 'Bearer ' + accessToken
And multipart file info = { read('classpath:data/testplanwithkey.json'), filename: 'testplanwithkey.json', contentType: 'application/json' }
And multipart file result = { read('classpath:JiraReports/cucumber.json'), filename: 'cucumber.json', contentType: 'application/json' }
When method post
And print response

How ever I am karate response
15:50:50.334 [print] {
"error": "Unexpected field (result)"
}

I have attached my karate result file for the reference. Please let me where I am going wrong.

[image]

Also I have tried the same with rest api and I am to upload result with that but not sure where I am going wrong with karate: `ResponseBody responseBody = given() .multiPart("results", new File(CUCUMBER_RESULT_FILE)) .mul .multiPart("info", "info.json", jiraExecutionJson.getBytes()) .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + jiraTokenGenerator.getXrayToken()) .post(JIRA_IMPORT_EXECUTION_MULTIPART_URL) .getBody();`

Comment: nothing else I can help with other than refer you to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54527955/143475

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to resolved this issue by using value: alternative to read in rare cases where something like a JSON or XML file is being uploaded and you want to create it dynamically. So earlier I was trying to read the json with
`And multipart file info = { read('classpath:data/testplanwithkey.json'), filename: 'testplanwithkey.json' }`
And this worked for me

```
 And def value = read('classpath:data/testplanwithkey.json')
And multipart file info = { value: '#(value)', filename: 'testplanwithkey.json' }
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem seems to be in your karate specification where you have a multipart named "result" and it should be named "results".

```
And multipart file results = ....
```

Just for reference, you can see here a [python code](https://github.com/Xray-App/xray-code-snippets/blob/main/use_cases/import_automation_results/python/import_results_cucumber_multipart_cloud.py) implementing a similar request.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, probably I moved I step ahead now but I am still getting a error while running the karate test:{"error":"Error parsing results file!"}
11:47:40.571 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] {
  "error": "Error parsing results file!"
}
Also I tried the to execute the same steps with the same files manually via postman tool and were are able to execute the test but getting issue with karate test

Comment: which error are you getting exactly @abdulkhan?

Comment: {"error":"Error parsing results file!"}
11:47:40.571 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] {
  "error": "Error parsing results file!"
}