# How to determine if the target scenario has been called by another scenario in the Karate framework

Tags: karate

I have a case where I need to find out how karate is determining if the target scenario has been called by another scenario, I am using https://github.com/kirksl/karate-maven-gradle for Integration with Report Portal, and in the Report Portal  I am seeing this issue https://github.com/kirksl/karate-maven-gradle/issues/14

When we run our tests, we see called scenarios ( Scenarios called from another feature file ) also in Report Portal. But I want to see only Scenarios that I have run ( not the called scenarios, that should be steps inside the test scenario)

Hierarchy in Report Portal should be :

Launches > Features > Scenarios (Main Test Scenario) > steps and steps of reusable (Called scenario steps)

In the below Image,
Roadster Store Login
and other scenarios below that are called scenarios from another feature file and
the main scenario is "Quotes Comparison for Cash"

[image]

```
This is the code
```

- def login = read('classpath:com/cdk/reusable_hooks/roadsterStore_Login.feature@login')

@Basic_Cash
Scenario Outline: Cash with Basic Test

- call login
- delay(2000)

Comment: this is not considered a priority by the project developers. the best option for you is to contribute code, or try a different option to integration, such as using the `RuntimeHook`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54527955/143475