# Storing karate report in database for analysis over a period of time

Tags: database, karate, cucumber-junit

Can we store karate report in the database? This will help us in doing various metrics over a period of time? Any suggestions?

Comment: see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54527955/143475 - we are also planning a commercial solution later this year, so if that is something you need sooner, contact us at https://karatelabs.io