# Allure Report with karate 1.0.1 generating report with just one test case

Tags: maven, jenkins, cucumber, karate, allure

I am working on a maven project where I am creating both cucumber reports and allure reports with karate 1.0.1 via jenkins. But even though the detailed cucumber reports are getting generated, I am getting only one test case in the allure report

My TestParallelRunner.java file:

```
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty" , "html:target/cucumber-html-reports", "io.qameta.allure.cucumber4jvm.AllureCucumber5Jvm","json:target/cucumber/cucumber.json"})
//@KarateOptions(tags = "~@ignore")
public class TestParallelRunner {
    
    @Test
    public void testParallel() {
        
        //String outputDir = "target//surefire-reports";
        Builder testRun = new Builder();
        testRun.path("classpath:com/api/automation/Features").outputCucumberJson(true).tags("~@ignore");
        Results results = testRun.parallel(3);
        generateReport(results.getReportDir());

        
       Assertions.assertEquals(0, results.getFailCount(), "There are some Failed Scenarios");
        

    }
    
    public static void generateReport(String reportDirLocation) {
        File reportDir=new File(reportDirLocation);     
        Collection<File> jsonFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(reportDir, new String[] {"json"}, true);
        //jsonFiles.add(File("cucumber-report.json"));
        List<String> jsonPaths = new ArrayList<>();
        
        //jsonFiles.add("cucumber-report-2.json");
        jsonFiles.forEach(file -> jsonPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        Configuration config = new Configuration(new File("target"), "Cucumber Report");
        ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonPaths, config);
        reportBuilder.generateReports();
        
        }

}
```

My pom.xml file:

```
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>
        <maven.surefire.version>2.22.2</maven.surefire.version>        
        <karate.version>1.0.1</karate.version>
        <allure.maven.version>2.11.2</allure.maven.version>
        <allure-junit5.version>2.17.3</allure-junit5.version>
    </properties>    

    <dependencies>         
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>${karate.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>       
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency> 

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.qameta.allure/allure-maven -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
    <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
    <version>${allure.maven.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.qameta.allure/allure-cucumber5-jvm -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
    <artifactId>allure-cucumber5-jvm</artifactId>
    <version>2.17.3</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.qameta.allure/allure-junit5 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
    <artifactId>allure-junit5</artifactId>
    <version>${allure-junit5.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
   </dependencies>

    <build>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/java</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Werror</compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
                <executions>
                <execution>
                 <goals>
                 <goal>test</goal>
                 </goals>
                 </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <systemProperties>
                    <property>
                    <name>allure.results.directory</name>
                    <value> ${project.build.directory}/allure-results</value>
                    </property>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
          </plugins>        
    </build>       
   </project>
```

My Allure reports in my jenkins pipeline:

```
allure([
          includeProperties: false, 
          jdk: '',
          properties:[],
          reportBuildPolicy:'ALWAYS', 
          results: [[path: '/allure-results']]
       ]
       )
```

But my the json file created in my allure-results folder contains only the following entry:

```
{"uuid":"XXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXX","historyId":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","testCaseId":"[engine:junit-jupiter]/[class:com.api.automation.TestParallelRunner]/[method:testParallel()]","testCaseName":"testParallel()","fullName":"com.api.automation.TestParallelRunner.testParallel","labels":[{"name":"junit.platform.uniqueid","value":"[engine:junit-jupiter]/[class:com.api.automation.TestParallelRunner]/[method:testParallel()]"},{"name":"host","value":"XXXXXX"},{"name":"thread","value":"XXXXXXX.main(1)"},{"name":"framework","value":"junit-platform"},{"name":"language","value":"java"},{"name":"package","value":"com.api.automation.TestParallelRunner"},{"name":"testClass","value":"com.api.automation.TestParallelRunner"},{"name":"testMethod","value":"testParallel"},{"name":"suite","value":"com.api.automation.TestParallelRunner"}],"links":[],"name":"testParallel()","status":"passed","stage":"finished","description":"","steps":[],"attachments":[],"parameters":[],"start":1652145767274,"stop":1652145775326}
```

Thus not getting a complete test execution picture the way cucumber report is showing :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points:

- `@CucumberOptions` is not supported in Karate, read the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#parallel-execution
- ensure that you tell Karate to emit the Cucumber JSON: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide#java-projects
- for good measure use the latest version (1.2.0) as of now
- Also refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54527955/143475

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Peter. I will try checking if upgrading to 1.2.0 helps. Also I am emitting the Cucumber JSON in my Runner file.
`testRun.path("classpath:com/api/automation/Features").outputCucumberJson(true).tags("~@ignore");`
Please let me know if this isn't correct?

Comment: @darklord84 looks correct but if you still need support, follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: @darklord84 Were you able to run get the allure reports finally? We are also in similar situation currently. If its working fine then may some code snippet if you share it will be helpful. Thanks!