# How to Integrate reportportal.io with karate 1.2.0

Tags: karate, reportportal

I am looking for the Integration of reportportal.io with the karate 1.2.0 version.

Comment: there is no direct support I am aware of. if you don't mind I'll close this question as a duplicate of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54527955/143475