# How to write a step in multiple line in Karate Framework?

Tags: karate

I'm calling an afterScenario function & for that I need to pass multiple parameter to log test step result to test management tool. My after scenario function looks like:
* configure afterScenario = function(){karate.call('Common.feature@qtestAutomation',{testdescription1: info.step1, expectedResult1: info.expectedResult1, status1: karate.scenario.stepResults[1].result.status})}

This will grow when test case has multiple steps so is it any better way to pass this parameters to afterScenario function or can we write this parameter in multiple line for better readability?

Answer (score 0):

Karate is not designed for this. What you are trying to do is better handled with a Java `RuntimeHook`. Refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54527955/143475