Qtest automation framework integration
I want to Integrate Qtest with karate framework used for API automation. I am using the below libraries of Qtest  group: 'com.qasymphony.qtest', name: 'qtest-sdk-java', version: '1.4.10' to integrate it.  I just want to know how to start for integrating it with the framework
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Set your qTest credentials
        String apiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY";
        String baseUrl = "YOUR_QTEST_BASE_URL";
        String projectId = "YOUR_PROJECT_ID";
        int testCaseId = 123; // Replace with your test case ID
        int testSuiteId = 456; // Replace with your test suite ID

        // Initialize qTest services
        Tokens tokens = new Tokens(apiKey, baseUrl);
        TestExecutionService testExecutionService = new TestExecutionServiceClient(tokens);
        TestDesignService testDesignService = new TestDesignServiceClient(tokens);

        // Create a test cycle under a specific test suite
        TestCycle testCycle = testExecutionService.createTestCycle(new CreateTestCycleRequest()
                .withProjectId(projectId)
                .withTestSuiteId(testSuiteId)
                .withTestCycle(new TestCycle().withName("Cycle1")));

        // Get the test case details
        TestCase testCase = testDesignService.getTestCase(new GetTestCaseRequest()
                .withProjectId(projectId)
                .withTestCaseId(testCaseId));

        // Create a test run for the test case within the test cycle
        TestRun testRun = testExecutionService.createTestRun(new CreateTestRunRequest()
                .withProjectId(projectId)
                .withTestCycleId(testCycle.getId())
                .withTestRun(new TestRun().withTestCase(testCase).withName("Thank u")));

        // Execute your Selenium tests and collect results and logs

        // For demonstration purposes, we'll assume test results and logs are collected
        String testStatus = "PASS"; // Replace with actual test status
        String logHistory = "Test executed successfully.\n" +
                "Step 1: Navigate to the website.\n" +
                "Step 2: Perform action X.\n"; // Replace with actual log history

        // Update the test run with test execution results and log history
        UpdateTestRunRequest updateRequest = new UpdateTestRunRequest()
                .withStatus(testStatus)
                .withLog(logHistory);

        testExecutionService.updateTestRun(testRun.getId(), updateRequest);
    }
}

this is the code i have been using but looks like token is not a class in Qtest sdks.

not sure about qtest, but generic information on connecting results to other systems can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54527955/143475
